# How to capture the open sequences in the list using python

Tags: python

I have two lists one is main list which contains all the elements. And other one is sequence list, which needs to be compared against the main list and extract the open and closed sequence patterns along with their main index locations.

Open Sequence Pattern: Sequence of pattern items occurring in a sequential order (Other elements can occur in between)

Closed Sequence Pattern: Strict pattern/ Exact match (Other elements won't occur in between)

E.G:

```
main_input_list = ['a','b','c','a','d','e','f','g','b','a','b','d','a']

sequence_input_1 = ['a','b','c']

Output = [[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]]

sequence_input_2 = ['b','a']

Output = [[(1,'b'),(2,'c'),(3,'a')],[(8,b),(9,a)],[(10,b),(11,d),(12,a)]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open and closed sequences"? What is the exact relationship between the input and the output?

Comment: I have updated the question again, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define two funcitons.

```
def get_closed_sequence_pattern(input_list, sequence_input):
    str_input = ''.join(input_list)
    str_sequence = ''.join(sequence_input)
    sequence_len = len(sequence_input)
    if str_sequence in str_input:
        start_index = str_input.index(str_sequence)
        return [(index, input_list[index]) for index in range(start_index, start_index + sequence_len)]
    else:
        return False

def get_open_sequence_pattern(input_list, sequence_input):
    try:
        start_index = input_list.index(sequence_input[0])
        end_index = input_list[start_index:].index(sequence_input[-1]) + start_index
    except:
        return False
    return [(index, input_list[index]) for index in range(start_index, end_index + 1)]
```

Then you can get what you want:

```
main_input_list = ['a','b','c','a','d','e','f','g']
sequence_input_1 = ['a','b','c']
print(get_open_sequence_pattern(main_input_list, sequence_input_1))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

--

```
sequence_input_2 = ['b','e']
print(get_closed_sequence_pattern(main_input_list, sequence_input_2))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

--
For duplicate problem (closed sequence pattern), you can use:

```
def get_all_closed_sequence_pattern(input_list, sequence_input):
    ans = []
    sequence_len = len(sequence_input)
    for i in range(0, len(input_list) - sequence_len + 1):
        if input_list[i: i+sequence_len] == sequence_input:
            ans.append([(index, input_list[index]) for index in range(i, i+sequence_len)])
    return ans
```

--

```
main_input_list = ['a','b','c','a','d','e','f','g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
sequence_input_1 = ['a','b','c']
print(get_all_closed_sequence_pattern(main_input_list, sequence_input_1))
```

--
Output:

```
[[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')], [(8, 'a'), (9, 'b'), (10, 'c')]]
```

--
For the duplicate problem of open sequence pattern, Your requirements for the output are vague. You can clear your needs first and make some attempts first.

Comment: Yes. This solves majority of the problem. But, you named function names differently please change from open to closed.

What if we have duplicate sequences? I have to extract all possible sequences from the main_input_list.
main_input_list = ['a','b','c','a','d','e','f','g','b','a','b','d','a']
sequence_input_1 = ['b','a']
print(get_closed_sequence_pattern(main_input_list, sequence_input_1))
print(get_open_sequence_pattern(main_input_list, sequence_input_1))

Answer (score 0):

I have used Heaven's approach and created final method to capture both open and closed sequences.

```
def get_all_seqs(input_list, sequence_input):
    out_put = []
    try:
        start_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(input_list) if x == sequence_input[0]]
        end_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(input_list) if x == sequence_input[-1]]
        for i in start_indices:
            for j in end_indices:
                if i<j:
                    out_put.append([(index, input_list[index]) for index in range(i, j + 1)])
        out_put = [item for item in out_put if bool(re.match(r"^"+"(.*)".join(sequence_input)+"+","".join([strr[1] for strr in item])))]
    except:
        pass
    return out_put
```